# integrate Node.js in Cordova application

Tags: android, ios, node.js, cordova

I have to integrate a Node.js code inside an Android application, the Node.js code simply takes data from a JSON in a server and give it out at 3000 port.
I want to know if is possible to integrate Node.js in the Cordova Android-iOS application. Like when I open the application, the Node.js (service) starts and after that the app.
Is something like that possible?

Comment: are you sure about that? I dont know about ios but you can run nodejs in android there isn't any method to auto-install also it with the application?

Comment: https://github.com/janeasystems/nodejs-mobile-cordova